# Python 3 - Tcl/Tk how to get filename from filedialog and change label

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to select a file and have the label show its name.

```
def onOpen():
    photo_label = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    pass


#photo code
photo = PhotoImage(file="smile.png")
photo_label = Button(image=photo, command=onOpen).grid()
#I am attempting to change text=photo_label to reflect the file name
text = Label(text=photo_label) # included to show background color
text.grid()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `StringVar` and pass it to the `textvariable` option of the label, so that each time the value of the variable is changed, the text of the label is too:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def onOpen():
    """ Ask the user to choose a file and change the update the value of  photo_label"""
    photo_label.set(filedialog.askopenfilename())

root = tk.Tk()
# StringVar that will contain the file name
photo_label = tk.StringVar(root)

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="smile.png")
tk.Button(root, image=photo, command=onOpen).grid()

text = tk.Label(root, textvariable=photo_label)
text.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Remark: `grid()` returns `None` so in your code,
 
`photo_label = Button(image=photo, command=onOpen).grid()` 

just assigned the value `None` to `photo_label`.